# Showing the parsed JSON data in a string

Tags: java, android, json

I am a beginner at the android studio. I have parsed some song names from a JSON file. i want to define it on java like

```
Songnames[]={"songname1","songname2","songnames3"};
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of the json and your code? And if i understand you correctly, you want an array or list of the song names, right?

Comment: If you parse the json from url, the output will probably be a string. But the question is, are you asking how to use it or store it in java? That would be great to see some codes however